# Constraint WebView to a set of URLs (RN Android)

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I am developing an application using React Native and I would like to have a WebView which can only access a certain set of domains, and cancels any request to any other domain. In iOS it can be done with the `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` event. For instance:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(event){
   if(event.url.startsWith("http://alloweddomain.net")) return true;
   return false;
}
```

However, the same event is not available for Android ([this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6478) was sadly rejected) and I would like to know if there's any way to achieve this behaviour using the React API or a third party package.

Comment: Did you tried "shouldInterceptRequest" ?

Comment: @sunilsunny Can't find that one in the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.28/docs/webview.html#webview). Could you point me to it? Thanks!

Comment: sry, I think  I misunderstood the question .I was talking about Android Webview https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: @sunilsunny No worries! It is nice to know, I might consider implementing that API call in native code. Thanks anyway :)